# How to make a database auto commit all transactions

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, locking, commit

I am using SQL Server 2005 with several databases.

Recently I backed up our main production database and re-attached it as a development or test database for development purposes.

For some reason this 2nd copy of the database won't commit my SELECT statements. Every statement I run a query on the database it "locks it" and won't release back to other users, unless I force a commit statement at the end of my script.

Is there a way to SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS to OFF so that I don't have to COMMIT all the time and lock the database from other users? And again, I don't want to use that statement in the query. I want to set it in the properties of the database in some way.

I read this, but it's not much help

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Thanks

Comment: You can go to `Tools>Options>Query Execution>SQL Server>ANSI` and check the checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That setting is not a database setting, but rather a client setting. Whatever client you are using to access the database is setting that option. So, technically, the answer to your question is "no", but you *can* change the client settings so that you have the desired effect.

Comment: Ahh no wonder I could not see it. I am using TOAD for SQL Server 6.1, and there is no such option (none that I could find) that does the same thing as in SSMS, like @Rahul mentioned above. I've set it in SSMS, but again I am not using that as my client. It's strange because in TOAD when we attached the production database back in 2008 none of this was an issue, but it only came up recently.